# join table - query for not associate with specific id

Tags: mysql, sql

I have join table between t_model and s_model.
there are many to many relationships between them.

t_id_s_id_table

| t_id | s_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 |

I want to get all t_ids which don't associate with s_id=1 by single query from this table.
so in above table, the expected result is only t_id=2.

My first try was:

````
```
SELECT t_id
FROM t_id_s_id_table
WHERE NOT s_id = 1
```
````

I got all of t_ids(1, 2, 3), that was not what I wanted.

My second try is not completed, but my query is like this..

````
```
SELECT
t_id,
JSON_ARRAYAGG(s_id) array
FROM 
t_id_s_id_table
GROUP BY t_id
```
````

then the result was the following table.

| t_id | s_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1, 2 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 1,3 |

I wanted to extract only t_id=2 from this table, but I couldn't the way to do it.

Could you tell me the best way to get expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an aggregation approach here:

```sql
SELECT t_id
FROM t_id_s_id_table
GROUP BY t_id
HAVING SUM(s_id = 1) = 0;
```